# Win football game by running backwards?

Tags: american-football

If a football team is one point behind with less than two minutes remaining, wouldn't the logical move be to run the ball back into their own end zone to score a 2-point safety? Even if you are in field goal range, the field goal is uncertain, but the 2-point safety is a sure thing and difference between 2 points and 3 points is meaningless in a one-point game.

Has any team won by doing this? If so, how far did they run backwards?

Comment: Are you suggesting that the team A, who is one point behind, run backwards to score a safety (which is 2 points for *team B*) and punt the ball back to team B after the safety with under 2 minutes remaining (in which team A is now behind by 3 points)? I may be ignorant to what you're suggesting, so I'm asking for clarification.

Comment: Okay, maybe I misunderstood, the 2 points is scored by the team without the ball? In that case the strategy would not work.

Comment: Correct. I posted this as an answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your suggestion would be foolish.

Rule 11, Section 5, Article 1 in the 2016 NFL Rulebook defines a safety as:

> - if the offense commits a foul in its own end zone or;
> - **when an impetus by a team sends the ball behind its own goal line, and the ball is dead in the end zone in its possession** or the ball is out of bounds behind the goal line.

To take your example, let's say Team A does what you suggest. They run backwards for a safety, fulfilling the requirement of "when an impetus by a team sends the ball behind its own goal line, and the ball is dead in the end zone in its possession." This gives *Team B* 2 points.

Rule 11, Section 5, Article 2 defines what takes place after a safety:

> After a safety, the team scored upon (Team A in your example) must put the ball in play by a
>   free kick (punt, dropkick, or placekick) from its 20-yard line. An
>   artificial or manufactured tee cannot be used. See 6-1-1-b and 6-1-3.

Thus, Team A, now 3 points behind, is free kicking the ball to Team B. Team B gains possession the ball with under 2 minutes remaining. As they are up by 3, Team B can proceed to attempt to run the clock out and win the game.

Comment: I see, I thought the 2 points went to the team with the ball, not the defending team, so it was a mistake on my part. I see that the main use of intentional safety would be to run down the clock when ahead by more than 2 points.

Comment: @TylerDurden Gotcha. If a team is up by more than 2 points, an intentional safety isn't needed to run down the clock (and you'll be giving the ball to the defending team, giving them a chance to score). Running/kneeling the ball and/or getting a first down is almost always enough to run the clock out.